# Java method parameter overriding

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, copy-constructor

I must have written it really wrong, because so far no one understood my point. From the beginning, here are all details needed:

We have a class called `Gem`, which has two children: `TimeGem` and `NormalGem`

Now we have an array, outside of the class, called `Gemlist`

```
public Gem[][] GemList = new Gem[8][8];
```

now `Gem` has a method:

```
public void swapGem(Gem A, boolean Auto, boolean isGame);
```

and two other methods:

```
public void swapGem(TimeGem A, boolean Auto, boolean isGame);
public void swapGem(NormalGem A, boolean Auto, boolean isGame);
```

Objects i keep in the `GemList` are of `TimeGem` and `NormalGem` type. When i call `swapGem` for one of them, i DON'T want to call

```
public void swapGem(Gem A, boolean Auto, boolean isGame);
```

but the one, which it actually is (one of those 2 derived ones). Inheritance is pretty much irrelevant here (my bad for mentioning it in the first place), because all we want is to call the method with the right argument.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  But, it doesn't make sense to me that `Gem` would have `swapGem`.  The `GemList` should have this method.

Comment: I hope those methods are not static!
When you override, even if the parameter is Gem the subclasses' methods must be called.Check your code please.

Comment: Nope, they're not static. Actually, i shouldn't have mentioned the overriding, cause it's rather irrelevant. The problem lies only in the parameter

Comment: The parameters must be same to be able to override a method.Otherwise it is just overloading.

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding, you are overloading swapGem, that's why u dont see another swapGem in the array.

To override you have to do something like this

```
class Gem {
public void swapGem(Gem A, boolean Auto, boolean isGame){
//code here
}
}

class TimeGem extends Gem{
@Override 
public void swapGem(Gem A, boolean Auto, boolean isGame){
//
}
}
```

so in ur client class

```
Game.LevelReference.GemList[x][y].swapGem(Game.LevelReference.GemList[x][y - 1], true, true);
```

then will be call the overriding method. This is an example of polimorphysm, u know at runtime what method will be called.